# What exactly was the relationship between The Vision and Wonder Man?

Tags: marvel, avengers

I used to be an Avengers fanatic (as a kid in the 70's), and I always thought The Vision was the coolest android ever. I can't remember what his deal was with Wonder Man...and/or Ultron???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a time when the two of them considered each other step-brothers of a sort. The Vision's human mental engrams were encoded from the believed-to-be-dead Simon Williams, aka, Wonder Man. This was some time ago when the Vision was far more human than writers have allowed him to be in recent years.

- Hank Pym created Ultron to be a robotic artificial intelligence that went rogue and became one of the Avengers greatest enemies. His hatred of his father was transferred to the entire Avengers and he eventually made better versions of himself until he became Ultron 5 and decided he would create his own artificial life.

[image]

*Debut of the Silver Age Vision: The Avengers #57 (Oct. 1968). Cover pencils by John Buscema.*

- Ultron would have been the equivalent of the Vision's evil father who created him from the synthetic body of the android Human Torch (from the WWII super-team, the Invaders) and planned to use him to infiltrate the Avengers. (Avengers Vol 1, #57, 1968.)
- Yes, you have seen Jim Hammond, the Original Human Torch flying around, there was a retcon that allowed Immortus (a time traveler from the future) to create two android bodies so one could become the Vision and the other remained Jim Hammond, the Human Torch. (Avengers 116 & 118, October/December, 1973)
- Instead of destroying the Avengers, the Vision revolts against his programming and joins the Avengers instead. This seemed to be a running trend in this "family" of rebelling against their creator. (Avengers Vol 1, #58)
- When Wonder Man returned to "life" such as an ionic being composed of energy can have, he and the Vision were quite close for a time until the Vision married the Scarlet Witch and she had a nervous breakdown which destabilized the Avengers.

[image: Wonder Man and the Vision bond after the "death" of Wonder Man's brother, the Grim Reaper]

*Vision and the Scarlet Witch #2, 1985 - Wonder Man and the Vision bond after the "death" of Wonder Man's brother, the Grim Reaper*

- Unfortunately, when the Vision is destroyed by Annihilus, his consciousness is uploaded into a computer. Unbalanced he tries to take over the world's computers and is eventually shut down. Immortus then steals the Vision and dismantles him. Dr. Pym puts the Vision back together but this time without the engrams of Simon Williams who at this point felt violated and refused to cooperate. This returned the Vision to his more machine-like condition he had after his creation. (West Coast Avengers #42 & #44)